# How to get a list box to disallow duplicate items?

Tags: c#, winforms

Bassicly im creating a program that reads information from an xml file into a lisbox and allows the user to transfer items in the list box to another listBox.

But i want to some how disallow multiple items from being imported from one listBox to the other. I thought i can somehow do an experession to check if the String already Exists in the listBox.

The reason i want to do this is because the user can click x amount of times in order to import items and it's unproffesional.

Any Help would be appreciated thank you.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!listBox.Items.Exists) // Random Idea which doesnt work
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!listBox.Items.Exists) // Random Idea which doesnt work
    {
    listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex]);
    }

}
```

That will work actually, but you need to use the `Contains` method. However, you may be missing one crucial point.

What type of items are you using to populate your `ListBox`?  `Exists` will call `.Equals` which, by default, uses *reference* equality. So, if you need to filter based on value, you need to override `.Equals` for your type and change the semantics.

For example:

```
class Foo 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Foo(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var x = new Foo("ed");
        var y = new Foo("ed");
        Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y));  // prints "False"
    }       
}
```

However, if we override `.Equals` to provide value type semantics...

```
class Foo 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Foo(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        // error and type checking go here!
        return ((Foo)obj).Name == this.Name;
    }

    // should override GetHashCode as well
}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var x = new Foo("ed");
        var y = new Foo("ed");
        Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y));  // prints "True"
        Console.Read();
    }       
}
```

And now your call to `if(!listBox.Items.Contains(item))` will work as you intended it to.  However, if you wish it to continue working you will need to add the item to both listboxes, not just `listBox2`.

Comment: The OP has said that all of the items already exist in listBox1 - So this solution seems over complicated... The simple Contains solution I posted seems more logical if the item already exists in the other listbox.  Just my thoughts, but you've already gotten the points ;-)

Comment: @Vijay: I recommended `Contains` as well, but it will still fail if he is creating a new instance with the same values and comparing that.  The OP didn't show us *where* he is getting these instances from, so I expanded a bit in case he ran into that problem next.  You're right though; if he doesn't need to override Equals he shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ListBox.Items.Contains(listBox1.SelectedItem)) // Random Idea which doesnt work
        {
        listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        }

    }
```